# Java WS RS - Post Entity Complex Object

Tags: java, web-services, java-ws

Currently trying to call a service which needs:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "a1": "stuff",
      "a2": "stuff",
      "a3": "stuff"
    }
  ],
  "b": "stuff",
  "c": "stuff",
  "d": "stuff"
}
```

I need to post my json query via java ws rs and was wondering how I could wrap all of this in an entity.

I tried making 2 wrappers:

```
class A {
   String a1;
   String a2;
   String a3;
}

class Wrapper {
   A a;
   String b;
   String c;
   String d;
}
```

But upon posting the entity:

```
webResourceEndPoint.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.json(wrapper);
```

I get an error 400.

Seems it can't read my json or understand the wrapper. How should I handle this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` JSON property is an array (see the `[` and the `]`).

Hence the `a` field of the `Wrapper` class must be defined as a `List<A>`:

```
class Wrapper {
   List<A> a;
   String b;
   String c;
   String d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, by doing the previous answer I got errors that led me to fix them which then led me to your answer and it's good to have a confirmation :)